# is it possible to change postgresql schema on receiver using logical replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a PostgreSQL 12 database set up to follow a remote database (version 12) using logical replication.

I do not control the sender database.

I need to perform queries on the DB  filtering records based on values contained in a column which is not indexed, queries takes a long time to execute and so I would like to add an index on that column.

According to this [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/logical-replication-restrictions.html) excerpt

> (Note, however, that there is no need for the schemas to be absolutely
> the same on both sides.)

as the schema is not replicated it's possible to have different schemas on the receiver.

My questions are:

1. can I add the index without breaking logical replication?
2. what will happen if the sender will eventually add the index in the future?

Comment: 1: yes, 2: nothing

Comment: Thank you, I accepted mustaccio's answer as this was a comment but I'd happily change it if a wider answer will be given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are, per [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)

1. yes
2. nothing